# Modify HTML contents for updating nodes in D3js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

The general recipe for modifying nodes that already exist in a d3 setup is:

```
var bound = d3.select('ul#myList').selectAll('li').data(myData);
var updating = bound.transition().attr('width', function(d) { return d.width; });
var entering = bound.enter().append('li').attr('width', function(d) { return d.width; });
```

However, there's an issue when trying to update the HTML contents of some thing. The `html()` method is not animate-able, so is not even available on transitioning selections (`.html` is undefined). In other words, the following doesn't work:

```
bound.transition().html(function(d) { return d.contents; });
```

Because `html()` is undefined;

The `text()` method is still available to replace the contents of the node, but that doesn't parse HTML tags.

So, how do I insert HTML and have it be interpreted as HTML into transitioning nodes in D3? A Codepen illustrating the problem can be found at http://codepen.io/MidnightLightning/pen/wBJGxr?editors=101

**EDIT**: Upon working with it further, it seems this issue is due to misunderstanding the difference between d3 Selections and Transitions.

The output `data()` is a Selection, while the output of `transition()`, `enter()`, and `exit()` are Transitions.

An alternative (and probably more in-line with the intended use) solution is to do:

```
var updating = d3.select('ul#myList').selectAll('li').data(myData);

// First insert elements needing to be added to the DOM
var entering = bound.enter().append('li');

// Modify un-transition-able elements
updating.html(function(d) { return d.contents; });

// Transition the transition-able elements
updating.transition().attr('width', function(d) { return d.width; });
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution I've found is to use the `each()` iterator and manipulate `.innerHTML` directly:

```
bound.transition.each(function(d) { this.innerHTML = d.contents; });
```

Is this the best way, or is there an existing function that provides this functionality?